# Is there a Schema.org markup for an Offer which has an order-level charge?

Tags: google, ecommerce, schema.org

I sell many custom products. The nature of the custom product industry is that there is a fee tacked onto the order itself, not the products. So a person ordering custom red cups and custom blue cups has the same fee as a person ordering only custom green lids.

Is there a way to pass this information into Google so my advertised price is represented alongside that order-level fee?

I see that [Google's Schema Offer reference](https://developers.google.com/schemas/reference/types/Offer) has an `addOn` section, but I think that really applies to up-selling. I am open to clever use, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `Offer` can reference a [`PriceSpecification`](http://schema.org/PriceSpecification) item with the [`priceSpecification`](http://schema.org/priceSpecification) property:

> One or more detailed price specifications, indicating the unit price and delivery or payment charges.

This definition refers to the three `PriceSpecification` sub-classes:

- [`DeliveryChargeSpecification`](http://schema.org/DeliveryChargeSpecification)
- [`PaymentChargeSpecification`](http://schema.org/PaymentChargeSpecification)
- [`UnitPriceSpecification`](http://schema.org/UnitPriceSpecification)

But if these aren’t appropriate for your case, there’s nothing wrong with using the `PriceSpecification` type directly.

However, if you can model it with [`addOn`](http://schema.org/addOn) as separate `Offer` (if it works for you to have a "customization offer", so to say), I think this would be a more suitable solution.

I can’t say if Google currently supports either of these, but I’d guess that the `addOn` way would more likely to be supported, because it’s defined to be an additional/optional offer, while `priceSpecification` could also refer to something that’s included in the price (and by using `PriceSpecification` instead of a more specific type, consumers don’t really have a chance to understand what this price specification is about).